# How to find the revision of a bazaar working copy? (like hg parent)

Tags: dvcs, bazaar

In case you have an un-updated working tree in bazaar reported by

```
bzr st
working tree is out of date, run 'bzr update'
```

how do you find out the working copy's revision number? (or the latest commit applied)

With Mercurial you can get it with `hg parents`, I'm looking for it's bazaar counterpart, or any workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it, it's `bzr version-info`.

What's very nice in it is that you can also format it's output via the `--custom --template='your settings'` parameter.

**Update:**

Even more simply, you can also use `bzr revno --tree` as well.